# How to verify a mobile app client has established a keep-alive https connection with Azure web service

Tags: http, azure, https, connection, keep-alive

Is there a way that can verify my app client in mobile has established a keep-alive https connection with my Azure web service? That during a period, requests from the same client will not do TCP/IC connect and HTTPS handshake.

I tried to use fiddler to capture packages between app client and azure service but seems useless because fiddler itself makes a keep-alive connection with server side.

And I know that http 1.1 has set keep-alive as default. However I just curious is there are any method can verify that. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find out? You say http 1.1 has it by default. However when I query my web api with Fiddler in http 1.1 the response doesn't show keep alive. If I query say facebook however it shows keep alive.